# Laravel: How to start redis on mac?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am trying to get redis working in my Laravel project on Mac.

Here is what I did so far:

1) I ran "composer require predis/predis" succesfully

2) I can see the predis folder in vendor folder

3) My CACHE_DRIVER has been set to redis in the cache.php and .env file

When I try to run redis in my project, I get the following error:

```
Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

Based on what I read online, it seems like my redis server is not started. How can I start it?

Comment: `predis` is a redis _driver_, not a redis _server_.

Comment: predis is a driver that allows you to interact with a Redis server more easily in PHP. Redis itself is a system package that needs to be installed, configured, and started. See https://medium.com/@petehouston/install-and-config-redis-on-mac-os-x-via-homebrew-eb8df9a4f298 for more info. This question is off topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install the redis server via `brew install redis`.  Be sure to start the redis daemon by running `brew services start redis`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution will help someone, I had issue that I have no control over the server to run the redis server as a service and I have to run it manually each time.

the solution is :

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        try {
            // Attempt to connect to Redis
            Redis::ping();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // If connection fails, start Redis server
            exec('redis-server --daemonize yes');
        }
    }
}
```